# Set point in aspx markup and jump to it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

is this possible using resharper or just visual settings to mark some line in aspx markup and then scroll the page and jump to selected line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean bookmarks? Using ReSharper you can press Ctrl-Shift-1 (or 2, or 3...or 9) to mark or unmark some line and then Ctrl-1 (or 2, or 3...or 9 respectively) to jump to it.

Using just Visual Studio press Ctrl+B,T to mark or unmark some line and then Ctrl+B,N to jump to the next marked line.

Maybe I just didn't understand what you need, then please try to clarify it.